# How can I generate and save a new text file each time program is run?

Tags: c++, text-files, filenames

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        blah blah blah
        if (newDataAvailable) {
            std::ofstream outfile;                                                                              
            outfile.open("C:/Users/admin/Documents/MATLAB/afile2.txt", std::ios::app);                  
            outfile << "Blah blah blah" << "\n";
            outfile.close();
```

Pretty much this code gets data from sensors and outputs it to a text file. The 'if' statement will loop itself every 10ms.

What I need to do is before the 'if' loop, I need create a unique file name, then once the code reaches the if loop, it will be able to `outfile.open("C:.../**FILENUMBER X.txt**",std::ios::app);`

In other words, I need this code to create a new filename each time the code is run. The only two ways I can think of are using something to generate a random number or use something to generate the date/time. (But note, while the if loop is running, it needs to be creating/opening the same text file. A new textfile name is only created if the code is stopped and run again)

I have close to no knowledge in c++ programming (I just need to edit the premade code I have), and all the solutions I've researched for don't make much sense to me so I thought id come and ask here.

Comment: Start at `1`, and begin looping upwards until you find a number that isn't taken. Hopefully you aren't leaving thousands of these files around, so it shouldn't be much of a problem to just search linearly for the next number. Failing that, just a timestamp instead of a sequential number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the file name with a post-fix that represents a sequence or a file number. For example, you name the first file as "yourFileName1", the second one as "yourFileName2", etc. You need to store the last file's sequence in a file. When you start your program for the first time, you set the file's sequence to 1. The next time you run the program, you read the last sequence from the sequence file "sequenceFile.txt" and increment it by 1. Before you terminate your program, you should store the last sequence back in the sequence file.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned int fileSeq;
    ifstream seqFileIn;
    ofstream seqFileOut;

    seqFileIn.open("sequeceFile.txt", ios::in);

    // If "sequenceFile.txt" exists, read the last sequence from it and increment it by 1.
    if (seqFileIn.is_open())
    {
        seqFileIn >> fileSeq;
        fileSeq++;
    }
    else
        fileSeq = 1; // if it does not exist, start from sequence 1.


    // Assume newDataAvailable = true
    bool newDataAvailable = true;

    if (newDataAvailable) {
        ofstream afile;
        string fileName = "afile" + to_string(fileSeq) + ".txt";

        cout << "File Name is " << fileName << endl;

        afile.open(fileName, ios::app);
        afile << "Blah blah blah! File sequence is " << fileSeq << "\n";
        afile.close();
    }

    // Before you exit your program, do not forget to store the last file sequence in "sequeceFile.txt".
    seqFileOut.open("sequeceFile.txt", ios::out);
    seqFileOut << fileSeq;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

based on the first suggestion:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //blah blah blah
    bool started = false;
    std::ofstream outfile;
    while(true) {//loop, could be while or for or whatever
      sleep(10); //you said it runs every 10ms

      if(!started){
          int fileno = 1;
          bool success = false;
          while(success &&fileno < MAX_INT) {
               ifstream ifs("C:/Users/admin/Documents/MATLAB/afile" + fileno  + ".txt", std::ios::read);// attempt read file to check if it exists
               success = ifs.good();
               ifs.close();
               fileno++;//increase by one to get a new file name
          }               
          outfile.open("C:/Users/admin/Documents/MATLAB/afile" + fileno  + ".txt", std::ios::app);
          started = true;
      }

       if (newDataAvailable) {


        outfile << "Blah blah blah" << "\n";

    }
 }
        outfile.close(); //moved out of loop so that it is not closed
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You can use date as filename. Get current date and clock then add your filename (replace afile2 with date). I think there are many different ways.